# Scheduled job is not starting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shedlock

I have been trying to implement the Shedlock on my spring boot application with no apparent use, I have used the formal guide available on https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock, please find below my configurations

Maven Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-mongo</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "10m")

public class IrishPubApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(IrishPubApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(MongoClient mongo) {
        return new MongoLockProvider(mongo.getDatabase("shedLock"));
    }
}
```

Scheduled Task:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${retry.job.cron.time}")
@SchedulerLock(name = "myTask", lockAtMostFor = "10m", lockAtLeastFor = "1m")
public void processMessage() {
   .....
}
```

No matter what I try the task does not start in the first place, any ideas

Comment: Does it start without ShedLock?

Comment: No, the job does not start and the collection is not created in MongoDB

Comment: Try to enable debug mode to see if any errors while initialization. Check if did you create sredlock table on db